# string.length() string.size() is not the same as in Eclipse with Cygwin and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, cygwin, string-length

When I build and run the following C++ code in Eclipse with Cygwin installed on Windows the result of line.length() is 1 larger than it is in Visual Studio 2012 installed on the same computer running Windows.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getInput(string, bool);

int main()
{
    string line = getInput("Please enter a string: ", false);
    cout << line.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}

string getInput(string message, bool newLine)
{
    string input;
    cout << message;
    if (newLine)
        cout << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    return input;
}
```

I have determined that this is due to the console.  If I run the same compiled binary using Command Prompt, the lenghth.size() is one less than it is in the CDT Build Console.  For example an input of 10 would result in a size of 2 in Command Prompt and size of 3 in CDT build console.  Any ideas on making this work using Cygwin?

Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Evaluation
Cygwin64 1.7.27
eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR1-win32 using Cygwin C++ Compiler

I would like the following output using Eclipse with CDT in the console:

```
Please enter a string: 10
2
```

Instead of the following output (I am currently seeing):

```
Please enter a string: 10
3
```

I have found that if I use MingW instead of Cygwin I do not encounter this issue.

Comment: What do you mean "making this work"?  You're getting different line termination behaviours from your terminals - that's not inherently broken - it's arbitrary, but it's easiest to use a terminal program that does what your binary expects.

Comment: Have you inspected what the extra char is? Looking at its ASCII code might give you a clue why this is happening.

Comment: I would like to change the line termination behavior in the CDT Build Console to match that of Command Prompt.

Comment: What happens if you use `fgets` instead of getline? Set aside a large char buffer inside your function and then convert the resulting buffer after using fgets to a std::string as you return it. Not sure about iostream but normally the C standard library is suppoed to treat newline characters in a consistent way across platforms when the stream is in the so-called "text mode" as opposed to binary mode

Comment: I have inspected the extra character and it is the CR return character.  In short the CDT Build Console is expecting Unix end of line characters which is just LF and when I press ENTER the line is the number 10 and CRLF instead of just LF.  I would like it the CDT Build Console to just interpret my ENTER as LF or to handle CRLF the same way as Command Prompt and consider it the end of line character.

Comment: My advice is not to use Cygwin unless you need the unix emulation. If you insist on Cygwin you can link an additional object file to change the newline behavior when compiling with cygwin: look here for details on CR/LF in Cygwin and the suggested linking fix: http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.api.cr-lf